# Javadoc для Java 8 не работает

Tags: eclipse, macos, javadoc, java-8

Есть проект с фичами Java 8, компилируется, исполняется как надо. Работаю в Eclipse, Mac OS. Но вот при генерации Javadoc вылезает много ошибок вроде таких:

> illegal start of expression `.map((num)->num.toString())`
>   ')' expected `.reduce((s1, s2)-> s1 + " " + s2);`

Раньше стояла JDK 6, восьмёрку относительно недавно прикрутил. Присмотревшись к созданию документации, обнаружил, что для генерации исполняется программа по адресу `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javadoc`. А вот по аналогичному пути для 1.8.0 такой не имеется. Вероятно, мне нужно поставить полноценный JDK 8. Где такой найти, этот с официального сайта был получен? Или отдельно эту программку, так как 230 МБ грузить в моих условиях весьма неудобно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У знакомого попросил его *javadoc*-файл. Он не запустился, чего и следовало ожидать. Было решено скачать последний update JDK8. К счастью, в нём *javadoc* имеется и работает исправно. В окошке создания документации Eclipse нужно самостоятельно указать путь, и всё получается на ура :)